# Very slow Spring Boot application startup

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple Spring Boot application that connects to a PostgreSQL database and serves as a JSON service. Somehow the startup has become very slow, see timings 10:37:10 and 10:38:00:

```
2015-05-09 10:37:09.649  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-05-09 10:37:09.651  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
2015-05-09 10:37:09.767  INFO 20880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-05-09 10:37:09.767  INFO 20880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2970 ms
2015-05-09 10:37:09.979  INFO 20880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-05-09 10:37:09.985  INFO 20880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-05-09 10:37:10.105  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
2015-05-09 10:37:10.214  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-05-09 10:37:10.233  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2015-05-09 10:37:10.585  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2015-05-09 10:37:10.587  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-05-09 10:37:10.589  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-05-09 10:37:10.968  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-05-09 10:38:00.023  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2015-05-09 10:38:00.041  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2015-05-09 10:38:00.274  INFO 20880 --- [lication.main()] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Any thoughts? Is there anything I can do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: i also have the problem even if the database in on my machine ! I noticed that it depends on the network my machine is connected to. At home no problem, all is fast. If i am at work, with a proxies and firewall everywhere, the startup hangs before Dialect resolution ... Maybe Hibernate tries wrong adresses .... Anyway the solution, below solves the problem in all cases.

Answer (score 66):

For Spring Boot you can set this in your application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

I also found that I needed to set another property or I would get the error "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set".  To rectify that I set this property:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

This reduced our startup time from about 100 seconds down to 12.

Comment: On MacOS 10+ you can execute on Terminal `scutil --set HostName "localhost"`. I think is an issue resolving the network host.

Comment: This helped with part of the issue. Now something else with the HibernateSessionFactory seems to be causing a slowdown.

Answer (score 11):

Problem solved using

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", "false");
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 10):

Contributing `application.yml` version of property setting.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

Answer (score 4):

When I point to database in AWS RDS server it takes 78 seconds.
After given this configuration it takes 52 seconds.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

And after given this configuration with the above configuration it takes only 10 seconds.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Comment: This solution changed my startup time from 8 minutes to few seconds!! Great!

Answer (score 2):

For dev environment, use the following property

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

This would be a bit risky for staging and prod environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the tests on a local server? Perhaps there's some problem with the database server URL, such as a non-resolvable hostname or an IPv6 DNS entry, connecting with the same connection string from another application (e.g. http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) could confirm the problem.

The delay is definitely logged when creating the database connection for the first time (either while loading the driver or performing the connection).

Comment: The server is remote, but it takes just a few seconds to connect using pgAdmin. And the driver seems to be loaded before the problem happens (I added a bit more logging).

Answer (score 0):

I found the startup takes long time when the db server is far, in my case it won't take time when using the localhost db, and it take about 20 seconds in product enviroment with db is in us and server is in jp.

Answer (score 0):

For springboot data JPA you need to add `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy` in `application.properties` file this would also reduce bootup time.

```
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the project [spring-startup-analyzer](https://github.com/linyimin0812/spring-startup-analyzer) to analyze startup time of spring application.

It generates an interactive Spring application startup report that lets you understand what contributes to the application startup time and helps to optimize it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I used the following piece of code

```
spring:
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        show-sql: false
        generate-ddl: true
        **hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
        properties:
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: none**
```